# jackrabbit: UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException when working with NodeTypeManager

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I'm working with Apache Jackrabbit using JCR. I want to create and register new Node Type according to [Example Page](https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExamplesPage). My problem is that i got `UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException` exception when calling `createNodeTypeTemplate` method.. Here is my JCR sample

```
Repository repository = new URLRemoteRepository("http://localhost:8080/rmi");
Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin","admin".toCharArray()));
NodeTypeManager nodeTypeManager = session.getWorkspace().getNodeTypeManager();
NodeTypeTemplate nodeType = nodeTypeManager.createNodeTypeTemplate();
```

Based on documentation the exception will throw if implementation does not support node type registration. But Jackrabbit example page shows that it support the registering new node types.So where is the problem?

Comment: What version of Jackrabbit are you using?

Comment: Thanks, version:  2.14.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because this operation is not implemented in the RMI remoting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll test it

Comment: It works, the problem is solved using TransientRepository